# Java: null pointer exception when unboxing Integer?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, guava

This code is causing a null pointer exception. I have no idea why:

```
private void setSiblings(PhylogenyTree node, Color color) throws InvalidCellNumberException {
    PhylogenyTree parent = node.getParent();

    for (PhylogenyTree sibling : parent.getChildren()) {
        if (! sibling.equals(node)) {
            Animal animal = sibling.getAnimal();
            BiMap<PhylogenyTree, Integer> inverse = cellInfo.inverse();
            int cell = inverse.get(animal); // null pointer exception here
            setCellColor(cell, color);
        }
    }
}
```

I've examined it in the debugger, and all the local variables are non-null. How else could this be happening? The BiMap is from Google Collections.

Comment: Well, he included the line the exception was thrown.  I don't think the NullPointerException stacktrace is helpful in this case, besides for pointing the line

Comment: See also *[What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384)*.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The null pointer exception is a result of unboxing the result of `inverse.get(animal)`.  If `inverse` doesn't contain the key `animal`, it returns `null`, "of type" `Integer`.  Given that the assignment is to an `int` reference, Java unboxes the value into an `int`, resulting in a null pointer exception.

You should either check for `inverse.containsKey(animal)` or use `Integer` as the local variable type to avoid unboxing and act accordingly.  The proper mechanism depends on your context.

Comment: it's exactly that, find more about autoboxing/unboxing here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/autoboxing-unboxing-java/

Answer (score 4):

Check for `inverse.containsKey(animal), BiMap<PhylogenyTree, Integer>`. The inverse might not have the animal.

Answer (score -1):

You must have a stacktrace. It says exactly what was the line where that happened. Post it and we can tell.

From all the posted code, I can "guess" one of these are a potential NullPointerException (NPE).

`node` may be null and calling `node.getParent`.

The node's parent may be null and invoking `parent.getChildren` may throw an NPE.

One of the siblings may be null and invoking `sibling.equals` may throw an NPE.

cellInfo may be null and `cellInfo.inverse` will throw it.

Finally the "inverse" returned may be null and `inverse.get()` will throw it.

Phew!!...

So, to avoid doing this wild guessings, why don't you just post your stacktrace and we find out?

It should something like:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at YourClass.setSiblings( YouClass.java:22 )
 at YourClass.setSiblng( YourClass.java: XX )
```

etc.. .