# HashMap with java

Tags: java, hashmap

i got this code:

```
public class MatriceMap extends AbstractMatrix {

HashMap<Position,Integer> valeurs;
public MatriceMap(int nbl, int nbc) {
    super(nbl, nbc);
    values = new HashMap<Position, Integer>();
}
@Override
public int getValue(int x, int y) {
    Position p=new Position(x,y);
    int m=valeurs.get(p);
    return m;
}
```

and i got an error with getValue method : java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Please post the whole exception.

Comment: Alternative duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811706/java-null-pointer-exception-when-unboxing-integer You are assigning an `Integer` to `int` and the unboxing will trigger a `NullPointerException` if it is `null` (eg because there is no value in the map).

Answer (score 1):

`int m=valeurs.get(p);` will throw a `NullPointerException` if `valuers.get(p)` returns `null`, due to the attempt to auto un-box the `null` value to a primitive `int`.

If your method would return an `Integer` instead, it would be able to return a `null` :

```
public Integer getValeur(int x, int y) {
    Position p=new Position(x,y);
    Integer m=valeurs.get(p);
    return m;
}
```

EDIT :

After seeing your comment that you can't change the return type of `getValeur`, your only option (other than returning a default value that represents null) is to throw an unchecked exception (or a checked exception if the method you are overriding is already throwing that exception or a super-class of that exception) if `valuers.get(p)` returns `null` :

```
public int getValeur(int x, int y) {
    Position p=new Position(x,y);
    Integer m=valeurs.get(p);
    if (m == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Invalid position " + x + "," + y);
    }
    return m;
}
```